# How do I debug an error in a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm getting this error with the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.size):
  paperclip (2.3.8) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:104:in `assign'
```

How can I debug this, seeing as though it's in a gem? If this was my code I would place a few `puts` to see what's going on, but I can't do that here. I'm using Rails 3.0.1

Comment: The issue may be because you passed nil to paperclip. Have you examined the stack trace, and can you post it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's my best shot.

- Open one of your controllers and add a `debugger` line to it. We need the debugger to kick in to set the breakpoint
- Next `run rails --debug`
- navigate to the page / controller with the breakpoint
- the debugger console will appear.
- run `Gem.find_files("attachment.rb")` <- I'll call $GEM_ROOT to the path that this returns
- run `list $GEM_ROOT/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:104` - this will show the code around the area where the error occurred.
- run `b $GEM_ROOT/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:$LINE` - replace $LINE for a good candidate for the breakpoint.
- run `cont`
- hit the page / action that causes the error, and the debug console should open at the break point.

I think there must be a way to get the path to the gem file programmatically, but I have no idea how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works; however, it is as simple as going to the gem source and inserting the `debugger` command where you would like to break.

Be careful about whether your inserted `debugger` command is reached when rails serves the request you are trying.  With a controller, you might not be entering the controller right away.  There are sometimes before filters or helper methods that shortcut the controller and return.  Think of the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) `before_filter :authenticate_user!` as an example.

If you use bundler, and most of us currently do, a `bundle show paperclip` command issued from your project root directory will show you where to find the source code for the `paperclip` gem.

Also, you need to restart the server after inserting the `debugger` statement.